# JQuery val() undefined for textarea with variable selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can use .text() to get the original text, but updated text isn't being grabbed with the .val() command. Any ideas?

```
function submitText(subText){ //import submit button id
var boxID="txtArea_"+subText; //rename so that it is the textArea id
alert(boxID); //Alerts as the correct id
alert($("#".boxID).val()); //still undefined
}
```

HTML is

```
<textarea id="txtArea_29__KPIs_0" style="width:100%;">First Comment                 </textarea>
```

First alert is returning "txtArea_29__KPIs_0", the second is undefined

Answer (score 3):

You have used php strings concatenation. Use `+` operator instead.

Correct way is: `$("#"+boxID).val();`

Ways of string concatenation in js:

```
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';

var result = a+b;
var result = [a,b].join('');
var result = a.concat(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate

```
alert($("#"+boxID).val()); //still undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
alert($("#" + boxID).val());
```

instead of `alert($("#".boxID).val());`

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry, getting back into this stuff after 5 years and going a bit slowly. No error had been showing in JS either...

Answer (score 0):

Use "+" sign to concatenate jquery selector instead of the "."

```
alert($("#" + boxID).val());
```